# How to remove the upper tabs from the UI?(i.e Layout, Modeling, Sculpting etc.)

Tags: development, source-code

I want to streamline the UI of Blender from the source, so I was wondering where I could find the code concerning those tabs because all of them are very overwhelming and I would prefer to either remove/hide them.

Blender Version 2.8

Comment: Hello :). Wouldn't it be easier to just keep 1-2 that you actually use?

Comment: @JachymMichal Nah, I just want blender to start as if those tabs were not there, I dont mind getting into the source code, also then it would be easier to introduce someone new to blender, it'll be less overwhelming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just right-click on those tabs and delete, with the possibility of deleting all of them except one: [image]

It's possible to rename them by double clicking on the text.
Alternatively, you can take lines 45 through 56 of the space_topbar.py file and comment them out:
[image]

Just a side note: The space_topbar.py file can be easily found by right clicking any of the top tabs and clicking "Edit Source", which will populate the file inside the script editor (via the file dropdown)